# Java X509 certificate extract from p7m file

Tags: java, certificate, bouncycastle, x509

I have a web service in Java (Spring) which receives p7m files and needs to check if the certificate used to sign the file is valid or has been revocated.
How can I extract the certificate from the p7m file and validate it through OCSP?
Does anyone have an example?

Comment: There is no any Java standard service to decrypt p7m, but a valid p7m has been signed with the public key linked to the private that you owns, so you need to verify the digital signature. If it is verified, then the certificate is yours

Comment: @pedrofb I think you have not understood well the problem. I have to extract the certificate used to sign the p7m file, but the file has not been signed by me, byt by another person. And my main problem is how to check the validity of that certificate through OCSP...

Comment: Surely!. Are you talking about S/MIME cryptographic protocol with PKCS#7? So, the email content is encrypted (.p7m). The sender wraps the email with your public key. You need the private key to decrypt. The extension would be .p7s if the email was signed. In this case, there is a x509 certificate embedded in pcks#7 message, that could be verified (trust & revocation via CRL / OCSP) In both cases, the answer is the same: Java standard does not process pkcs#7 format. You need a cryptographic library like bouncycastle. Also you can use it to check trust and revocation